# Getting only the value field from the Cloudwatch api's

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have some data that are retried from the cloudwatch api's. Specifically I have used [`listMetrics`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/AmazonCloudWatchClient.html#listMetrics%28com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.model.ListMetricsRequest%29). The data that I got from this call is :

```
{Metrics: [{Namespace: Testing, MetricName: hello123, Dimensions: [{Name: name, Value: 1425, }], }, {Namespace: Metric from grails, MetricName: hello123, Dimensions: [{Name: name, Value: 1068, }], },
```

That was the correct data as I would expect. I need a way to return only the `value` fields. Not others things. Is there any way to do this, in java?

#### Edit:

The code that I have used for creating the metrics is :

```
MetricDatum metricDatum = new MetricDatum().withMetricName("hello123").withValue(80.0)
Dimension tableDimension = new Dimension()
tableDimension.withName("hello123")
tableDimension.withValue("somvalues")
Collection<Dimension> values = new ArrayList<Dimension>();
values << tableDimension
metricDatum.withDimensions(values)
cloudWatch.putMetricData(new PutMetricDataRequest().withNamespace("Metric from grails").withMetricData(metricDatum))
```

And for listing out the dimension values, I use :

```
DimensionFilter tableDimension2 = new DimensionFilter() 
tableDimension2.withName("hello123")
Collection<DimensionFilter> values2 = new ArrayList<DimensionFilter>();
values2 << tableDimension2
query = new ListMetricsRequest().withNamespace("Testing").withDimensions(values2)
def result = amazonWebService.cloudWatch.listMetrics(query)
```

Where I'm making the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ListMetrics API call in CloudWatch returns only metric definitions. The values you see in the response of ListMetrics calls are not the datapoint values, but dimension (name, value) pairs which is a part of metric definition along with the metric name and the namespace.

In order to get the datapoint values that you submitted, use **GetMetricStatistics** API call. You can't invoke it for a set of metrics. It works only for individual metric and returns datapoint values for requested time interval. Think of it as a call to get datapoints to build a single chart.

Your overall logic can probably go like this: 1) call ListMetrics 2) for every result returned in ListMetrics, call GetMetricStatistics.